# How to redirect websites to .dev domain using xampp ?

Tags: xampp

I started to use DesktopServer recently. However, I understand now that all it does to me currently is creating .dev domain for every website I install. Basically, I have to manually move my wordpress website to live server anyway.

So I was thinking instead of buying DesktopServer license, I better find out how to glue the .something domain to the websites that run on localhost.

Would you know how to do this (free)? :)

Comment: You want to redirect the global domain name to a site that is hosted on your workstation?

Comment: yes, i want to do that. exactly :-)

Comment: This is not a good idea. You're going to want to have your site on a proper server that is meant for this purpose.